# Winter bash results: 278 users have earned a total of 766 hats! [completed]

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

The annual [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) has been completed.

> 278 users have earned a total of 766 hats!! (*Awesome!*)
>
> Graphic Design [ranked in at 57th.](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) (Great Job!!!)

[Graphic Design's full leaderboard can be seen here.](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)

---

Our top 10:

1. [WELZ](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/63979/welz) - 22 hats.
2. [Cai ♦](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/52050/cai) - 18 hats.
3. [Scott](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3270/scott) - 15 hats.
4. [DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ ♦](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/9447/) - 13 hats.
5. [Westside](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/70987/westside) - 10 hats.
6. [Billy Kerr](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/89608/billy-kerr) - 9 hats.
7. [user287001](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/82991/user287001) - 9 hats.
8. [Vincent ♦](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/5498/vincent) - 8 hats.
9. [Lucian](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/62949/lucian) - 7 hats.
10. [joojaa](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa) - 7 hats.

---

List of all [2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304340/358161)

---

<sup>Note: Adapted from the [Travel Meta Post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4588/70154)</sup>

Comment: Just a general reminder for everybody: The normal rules still apply. Abuse of privileges, others, the site, sockpuppets, or other shenanigans will be reprimanded as usual, even if it’s just to get a hat.

Comment: Post no longer relevant but should be kept as an archive.